# Conditions on every character of input

Tags: java

I have created a text box on front end and the input I want to validate on the server side. The input has some conditions:

1. The first character should be integer from 0-9.
2. The second character should be alphabet from A-Z.
3. The third should be either an integer or an alphabet.
4. The input should be of length 3 not more or less.

How to achieve this?

I was trying to split:

```
String str=request.getParameter("name");
String[] str1=name.split("");
```

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Did you try regular expression?

Comment: I dont know much about regular expression..

Comment: Try a regex for matching your string. In this case it should be something like String regex = "[0-9][A-Z]^[A-Z0-9a-z]";

Comment: In that split variable i have to test?

Comment: @Prof yes. You can compare that with your Substring.

Comment: Can u give the snippet. I was trying to compare through index so can u provide the snippets

Comment: Try this [https://regex101.com/r/F249gc/](https://regex101.com/r/F249gc/1). Use "code generator" to get sample code

Comment: Thanks how to fix the length it should be not less or more than that

Comment: @Prof the above regex covered the length validation as well. Test with different string lengths.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code to find out about the match according to your requirements, also in this case I have three parenthases to ensure that length is exact three characters.

```
 String str = "asdf123 1a2 2aa";
    String[] strArr = str.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<strArr.length;i++)
    {
        if(strArr[i].matches("^[0-9][A-Za-z][A-Z0-9a-z]$")) /*Regex should be according to your requirements.*/
            System.out.println("Matches");
        else
            System.out.println("Doesn't match");
    }
}
```

Comment: So i have to just place my regex and the input which randomly you gave should be replaced with request.getPrameter("name")

Comment: Thanks.. and length issue?

Comment: The length is also exact 3 characters. I have used in  this regex just three [][][]. That shows it must have three chracaters (Not more or less).

Comment: You might also want to provide anchors to the start and end to match the whole entry to the provided regex. `^[0-9][A-Za-z][A-Z0-9a-z]$` [see regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2lWwFI/2)

Comment: @Prof could you please show your String input that you are providing in str1?

Comment: I am giving 1A1 and 1AA

Comment: @Prof on my side, it shows the correct answer. Saying "Matches". Could you debug the strigns which are being passed for the comparison and check, whether they are correctly passed or not?

Comment: If i am printing on console str1 its showing some junk values but when i apply for each loop then prinitng it showing split values that is all the chracter in a new line

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing correct string to array? Because, what I see from the code is you're using "name" as a string instead of "str". And as per the output you're getting, seems like you are splitting the string with no specific value. That's why it is stored as an individual character.

Comment: Name is the field name of the front end. So i am.getting the parameter here

Comment: Okay fine. But if you split a string in java with just "" then it only returns single character. On what basis you want to split the String?

Comment: Index basis so that it can be easy to validate those condtions

Comment: Post here the whole string. Because, "index" basis isn't making it clear.

Comment: I want user to enter any string of length 3 following those conditions mentioned above.

Comment: Try splitting it with str.split(" "); instead of name.split("");